# How to transfer data from one table of a database to a table in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to transfer data from a table of one database to a table in another database, For that I wrote this SQL

```
INSERT INTO 3tier-loginmodule-linq..tbl_rolll(Roll_id,Roll_Name)
   SELECT 
       Roll_id, Roll_Name 
   FROM 
       LoginMaster..tbl_roll;
```

But I get an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '3'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets around object's names

```
INSERT INTO [3tier-loginmodule-linq].....etc
```

Or use double quotes as suggested in the comment

```
INSERT INTO "3tier-loginmodule-linq".....etc
```

Comment: @piyushprajapati please mark it as answer if it answers your question. Thanks

Comment: i am very late @BICube , was in jungle .You are correct